# For this periodic continuous $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, and $f_n(x):=g(x/n)$, does $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converge uniformly?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, proof-verification

I can not find a counterexample although I have the feeling it is not true.

Let  $\ g: \mathbb{ R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous function

$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ g(x+1) = g(x)$

$g(0) = 0$

Let $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \  f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ f_n(x) = g(\frac{x}{n})$

Then $ \ (f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \ $ is uniform convergence in $ \ \mathbb{R} \ $ to $0$

So clearly we can see that there is a pointwise convergence $\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ $ to $0$

And because there is a cycle I need to check only what is happening in $[0,1]$

foreach $ \epsilon \ \exists x\in [0,1] \  g(x) = \epsilon $ so there must be a such a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that even for the "worst" $x$ we can say that 
$|g(\frac{x}{n})| < \epsilon$

This is my unformal proof.

So, is the proof good ?

Am I right ?

If it is not true, please explain to me what am I doing wrong and give a counterexample.

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: I took a shot at the title: let me know if I completely missed your question.

Comment: You did not missed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the definition

$$f_n(x) = g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right),$$

is is clear that

$$f_n(\mathbb{R}) = \{ f(x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{ g(y) : y \in \mathbb{R}\} = g(\mathbb{R}) = g([0,\,1]).$$

So, for all $n$, we have $\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert f(x) - g(0)\rvert = \max\limits_{y\in [0,\,1]} \lvert g(y) - g(0)\rvert$.

Hence the sequence converges uniformly on all of $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $g$ is constant.

$f_n$ converges uniformly to $g(0)$ on all *bounded* subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, however.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I am not sure I got u.If I understood u correctly you say that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ only if $g = 0$, which is obvious. but what about this example: $g(x) = x \ $ if $ \ 0 \leq x \leq 0.5 $ and $g(x) = 1 - x \ $ if $ \ 0.5 < x \leq 1 $ and so on for all the other cycles ($[1,2], \ [2,3], \ ... $). according to what u said my function is counterexample to the above statement. But the way I see that and explained foreach $ \epsilon \ $ there must be $N \in \mathbb{N} \ $ big enough such that for all $ \ x \ $ $|g(\frac{x}{n})| < \epsilon \ $, am I  wrong ?

Comment: @wantToLearn With that example, you have $g(1/2) = 1/2$, so $f_n(n/2) = 1/2$, and that means for $0 < \varepsilon < \frac12$, you don't have $\lvert f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. The convergence is pointwise, even locally uniform, but not uniform.

Comment: Ohh... u are right. Thank u !!